# Sql Table Left outer join result Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Product1

Purchase quantity from 3 invoices are 50+100+50 = 200 and

Sale quantity from 1 invoice is 10

I am using below code for getting the result as

```
Total Purchase - Total Sale = Closing Qty 
     200       -      10    = 290
```

but I am getting the wrong result as shown in the attached image:

[image]

Please guide me to correct my code

```
SELECT 
    P.PRODUCT as PRODUCTNAME,
    P.QUANTITY AS PURCHASE,
    ISNULL(S.QUANTITY, 0) AS SALE,
    ISNULL(P.QUANTITY, 0) - ISNULL(s.QUANTITY, 0) AS CLOSINGQTY
FROM 
    [PurchaseData] P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [DeliveryData1] S ON P.Product = s.PRODUCT
```

Comment: What tabular results do you want?

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with aggregates from different tables, don't join the tables and aggregate then, but aggregate first and join the aggregates:

```
select
  p.product as productname,
  p.sum_quantity as purchase,
  coalesce(s.sum_quantity, 0) as sale,
  p.sum_quantity - coalesce(s.sum_quantity, 0) as closingqty
from
(
  select product, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
  from purchasedata
  group by product
) p
left join
(
  select product, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
  from deliverydata1
  group by product  
) s on s.product = p.product;
```

I've replaced `ifnull` with `coalesce`, so the query is fully standard SQL compliant.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten........now the query is working as expected result.....Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 0):

If you want the final result you should use sum  and group by

```
      SELECT 
        P.PRODUCT as PRODUCTNAME,
        sum(P.QUANTITY AS PURCHASE),
        sum(isnull(S.QUANTITY,0)) AS SALE,
        sum(isnull(P.QUANTITY,0))-sum(isnull(s.QUANTITY,0)) AS CLOSINGQTY

    FROM [PurchaseData] P LEFT OUTER JOIN [DeliveryData1] S ON P.Product = s.PRODUCT
    GROUP BY P.PRODUCT
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a problem because you have multiple purchase records for a given product.  If that is the case, then just aggregate *before* the `JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(S.QUANTITY, 0) AS SALE,
       COALESCE(P.QUANTITY, 0)-COALESCE(s.QUANTITY, 0) AS CLOSINGQTY
FROM (SELECT p.product, p.quantity
      FROM PurchaseData P
      GROUP BY p.product
     ) p LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     DeliveryData1 S
     ON P.product = s.producct;
```

Actually, I'm unclear which of the two tables has the duplicates -- or even if both do.  So, you might need to do something similar for `S`.